# How to understand the while loop in this code?

Tags: python, while-loop

This is lab 1 from CS61A. I don't understand the answer.

For question 1, why is it an infinite loop? Is it because  means  has a value?

```
>>> positive = 28
>>> while positive:
...    print("positive?")
...    positive -= 3
______
```

For question 2, why the program end after it printed -12, -9, and -6?

```
>>> positive = -9
>>> negative = -12
>>> while negative:
...    if positive:
...        print(negative)
...    positive += 3
...    negative += 3
______
```

I am still a beginner of it and thank you for answering my question.

I tried to use PythonTutor but I still not understand why.

Comment: The while loop breaks when it’s condition is false. The only number that is "false" here is 0.

Comment: The `while` loop will continue while the variables are *truthy*. For numbers, only `0` is *falsey*, any other number is truthy. If the number in the condition never hits exactly `0`, it'll continue forever…

Comment: In the first example, `positive` is an integer.  All integer values are considered to be "true", except for zero.  `positive` is never equal to zero, because 28 is not a multiple of 3.